# LiveAgent auto create new custom object

Tags: api, liveagent

On the configuration for LiveAgent in the service console, you can have it automatically create a new case, a new account, a new lead, etc.

Salesforce has really come a long way with this product.  Registered users on our portal have their account open automatically for the agent.  The new automated invites are super cool.

But there's no option to open a new custom object (we need that).

Is there something in the LiveAgent API that would make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to open a new custom object after it has been created. Below is the sample deployment code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la6cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/29.0/deployment.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.enableLogging();
    liveagent.addCustomDetail("Case Subject", "Problem with my iPhone");
    liveagent.addCustomDetail("Case Status", "New", false);
 liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").map("Subject", "Case Subject", true, false, true).map("Status", "Case Status", false, false, true).showOnCreate(); 


liveagent.init('https://d.la6cs.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '<>', '<>');
</script>
```

Comment: So instead of case I could specify Something__c and some of its fields?